# The distribution can not be extended to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: distribution-theory

\begin{equation*}
\langle u, \varphi \rangle= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\varphi^{(k)}(\frac{1}{k}) \quad \varphi \in C^{\infty}_{c}((0,+\infty))
\end{equation*} define a distribution in $\mathcal{D}'((0,+\infty))$.

I want to show that there isn't $v \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$v|_{(0,+\infty)} =u,$$ that is $\langle v, \varphi \rangle=\langle u, \varphi\rangle \quad \forall \, \varphi \in C^{\infty}_{c}((0,+\infty)) \subset C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}).$ By contradiction, I thought about finding a sequence in $C^{\infty}_{c}((0,+\infty))$ such that \begin{align*}
\varphi_j \rightarrow 0 \quad \mbox{em} \,\, C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})\end{align*} but $v(\varphi_j)$ doesn't converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$. However I don't know which sequence I should choose.

I appreciate any answer or suggestion on how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, $\phi^{(k)}(1/k)$ instead? If so, consider that if there is an extension, then there is $r>0$, $n \geq 0$ such that $\sum_{p \leq n}{\|\psi^{(p)}\|_{\infty}}$ controls $u(\psi)$ for all $\psi \in C^{\infty}_c((0,r))$. Then take the $(k+1)$-th antiderivative of a function that is zero away from $1/(k+1)$, and peaking at $1/(k+1)$ with a small $L^1$ norm.

Comment: What is the order of $u$ on $(\epsilon,2)$? What would be the order of $u$ on $(-\epsilon,2)$?